# Writing CMake file for Fortran project with both gfortran and mpifort

Tags: cmake, fortran, gfortran, openmpi

I have a project where some f90 files need to be compiled using the regular gfortran compiler and some need to be compiled by using the mpifort wrapper. I don't know how to properly write the CMake file to accomodate this. Also, I have never used CMake before and am not familiar with it, but I'm trying to understand from documentation and (largely outdated) tutorials.

My project directory looks as follows:

```
├── CMakeLists.txt
├── README.md
├── bin
├── build
├── compile
├── src
│   ├── CMakeCache.txt
│   ├── CMakeFiles
│   │   ├── 3.8.1
│   │   │   ├── CMakeCCompiler.cmake
│   │   │   ├── CMakeCXXCompiler.cmake
│   │   │   ├── CMakeDetermineCompilerABI_C.bin
│   │   │   ├── CMakeDetermineCompilerABI_CXX.bin
│   │   │   ├── CMakeDetermineCompilerABI_Fortran.bin
│   │   │   ├── CMakeFortranCompiler.cmake
│   │   │   ├── CMakeSystem.cmake
│   │   │   ├── CompilerIdC
│   │   │   │   ├── CMakeCCompilerId.c
│   │   │   │   ├── a.out
│   │   │   │   └── tmp
│   │   │   ├── CompilerIdCXX
│   │   │   │   ├── CMakeCXXCompilerId.cpp
│   │   │   │   ├── a.out
│   │   │   │   └── tmp
│   │   │   └── CompilerIdFortran
│   │   │       ├── CMakeFortranCompilerId.F
│   │   │       ├── a.out
│   │   │       └── tmp
│   │   ├── CMakeDirectoryInformation.cmake
│   │   ├── CMakeOutput.log
│   │   ├── CMakeTmp
│   │   ├── Makefile.cmake
│   │   ├── Makefile2
│   │   ├── TargetDirectories.txt
│   │   ├── cmake.check_cache
│   │   ├── feature_tests.bin
│   │   ├── feature_tests.c
│   │   ├── feature_tests.cxx
│   │   ├── progress.marks
│   │   └── streetcanyon.dir
│   │       ├── DependInfo.cmake
│   │       ├── INC_BBB.f90.o
│   │       ├── INC_BBB.f90.o.provides.build
│   │       ├── INC_BC.f90.o
│   │       ├── INC_BC.f90.o.provides.build
│   │       ├── INC_BOUNDC.f90.o
│   │       ├── INC_BOUNDC.f90.o.provides.build
│   │       ├── INC_BUOY.f90.o
│   │       ├── INC_BUOY.f90.o.provides.build
│   │       ├── INC_COEF.f90.o
│   │       ├── INC_COEF.f90.o.provides.build
│   │       ├── INC_COEFB.f90.o
│   │       ├── INC_COEFB.f90.o.provides.build
│   │       ├── INC_GEO.f90.o
│   │       ├── INC_GEO.f90.o.provides.build
│   │       ├── INC_INDEX.f90.o
│   │       ├── INC_INDEX.f90.o.provides.build
│   │       ├── INC_OBSTACLE.f90.o
│   │       ├── INC_OBSTACLE.f90.o.provides.build
│   │       ├── INC_PAR.f90.o
│   │       ├── INC_PAR.f90.o.provides.build
│   │       ├── INC_PRINT.f90.o
│   │       ├── INC_PRINT.f90.o.provides.build
│   │       ├── INC_SOURCE.f90.o
│   │       ├── INC_SOURCE.f90.o.provides.build
│   │       ├── INC_STAT.f90.o
│   │       ├── INC_STAT.f90.o.provides.build
│   │       ├── INC_TIME.f90.o
│   │       ├── INC_TIME.f90.o.provides.build
│   │       ├── INC_TITLE.f90.o
│   │       ├── INC_TITLE.f90.o.provides.build
│   │       ├── INC_TREES.f90.o
│   │       ├── INC_TREES.f90.o.provides.build
│   │       ├── INC_UVW.f90.o
│   │       ├── INC_UVW.f90.o.provides.build
│   │       ├── INC_VEC.f90.o
│   │       ├── INC_VEC.f90.o.provides.build
│   │       ├── INC_WALL.f90.o
│   │       ├── INC_WALL.f90.o.provides.build
│   │       ├── build.make
│   │       ├── cmake_clean.cmake
│   │       ├── cmake_clean_Fortran.cmake
│   │       ├── depend.internal
│   │       ├── depend.make
│   │       ├── flags.make
│   │       ├── fortran.internal
│   │       ├── inc_bbb.mod.stamp
│   │       ├── inc_bc.mod.stamp
│   │       ├── inc_boundc.mod.stamp
│   │       ├── inc_buoy.mod.stamp
│   │       ├── inc_coef.mod.stamp
│   │       ├── inc_coefb.mod.stamp
│   │       ├── inc_geo.mod.stamp
│   │       ├── inc_index.mod.stamp
│   │       ├── inc_obstacle.mod.stamp
│   │       ├── inc_par.mod.stamp
│   │       ├── inc_print.mod.stamp
│   │       ├── inc_source.mod.stamp
│   │       ├── inc_stat.mod.stamp
│   │       ├── inc_time.mod.stamp
│   │       ├── inc_title.mod.stamp
│   │       ├── inc_trees.mod.stamp
│   │       ├── inc_uvw.mod.stamp
│   │       ├── inc_vec.mod.stamp
│   │       ├── inc_wall.mod.stamp
│   │       ├── link.txt
│   │       └── progress.make
│   ├── INC_BBB.f90
│   ├── INC_BC.f90
│   ├── INC_BOUNDC.f90
│   ├── INC_BUOY.f90
│   ├── INC_COEF.f90
│   ├── INC_COEFB.f90
│   ├── INC_GEO.f90
│   ├── INC_INDEX.f90
│   ├── INC_OBSTACLE.f90
│   ├── INC_PAR.f90
│   ├── INC_PAR.f90_8ob
│   ├── INC_PRINT.f90
│   ├── INC_SOURCE.f90
│   ├── INC_STAT.f90
│   ├── INC_TIME.f90
│   ├── INC_TITLE.f90
│   ├── INC_TREES.f90
│   ├── INC_UVW.f90
│   ├── INC_VEC.f90
│   ├── INC_WALL.f90
│   ├── Makefile
│   ├── cmake_install.cmake
│   ├── grid_binary
│   ├── grid_binary(8\ obsttacles)
│   ├── inc_bbb.mod
│   ├── inc_bc.mod
│   ├── inc_boundc.mod
│   ├── inc_buoy.mod
│   ├── inc_coef.mod
│   ├── inc_coefb.mod
│   ├── inc_geo.mod
│   ├── inc_index.mod
│   ├── inc_obstacle.mod
│   ├── inc_par.mod
│   ├── inc_print.mod
│   ├── inc_source.mod
│   ├── inc_stat.mod
│   ├── inc_time.mod
│   ├── inc_title.mod
│   ├── inc_trees.mod
│   ├── inc_uvw.mod
│   ├── inc_vec.mod
│   ├── inc_wall.mod
│   ├── mpi_par.f90
│   ├── source
│   ├── streetcanyon.f90
│   └── streetcanyon.f90~
```

In the `./src/` directory the `streetcanyon.f90` and `mpi_par.f90` need to be compiled using `mpifort`, the rest can be done through `gfortran`. `streetcanyon.f90` needs to be compiled to the final executable. I have tried using the following `CMakeList.txt` which is contained in the project root dir:

```
#./CMakeList.txt
cmake_minimum_required (VERSION 3.8.0)
project(mpi)
enable_language (Fortran)

file(GLOB SOURCES src/*.f90)

add_executable(streetcanyon ${SOURCES})
```

I also don't know if I'm following the appropriate project structure for Fortran.

Comment: Why can't you compile everything with the MPI wrapper? That is what I do in my projects.

Comment: That might be possible, but I thought it might be bad practice. I don't know exactly what goes on 'under the hood' when calling `mpifort` instead of `gfortran` for example.

Comment: Nothing bad really. I can't see why would one not compile everything by the MPI wrapper. How do you even decide which yes and which no...?

Comment: @VladimirF, I suppose the ones which have the `use mpi` statement

Comment: There is no reason for such a division.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use CMake's [FindMPI](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.8/module/FindMPI.html) module.  It will extract the compile flags and libraries from `mpifort` and make them available as regular CMake variables.  All you have to do is apply those flags to your library.  The only hard part is that there are several different things that have to get applied.  Here's an example of how you'd use it:

```
cmake_minimum_required (VERSION 3.8.0)
project(mpi)
enable_language (Fortran)

find_package(MPI)
if(NOT MPI_Fortran_FOUND)
    message(FATAL_ERROR "Could not find Fortran MPI.  Please set MPI_Fortran_COMPILER to point to the mpifort wrapper.")
endif()

include_directories(${MPI_Fortran_INCLUDE_PATH})
add_compile_options(${MPI_Fortran_COMPILE_FLAGS})

file(GLOB SOURCES src/*.f90)

add_executable(streetcanyon ${SOURCES})
target_link_libraries(streetcanyon ${MPI_Fortran_LIBRARIES})
set_property(TARGET streetcanyon APPEND_STRING PROPERTY LINK_FLAGS "${MPI_Fortran_LINK_FLAGS}")
```

This will compile all of the streetcanyon sources the way that mpifort would have compiled them, which should be fine in 99% of use cases.  If you really want to only compile some files like mpifort would have, like you said, then instead of

```
add_compile_options(${MPI_Fortran_COMPILE_FLAGS})
```

you can pass the MPI compile options to specific source files only, with a bit of fiddling:

```
set(MPI_SOURCES foo.f90 bar.f90...)
set(NO_MPI_SOURCES baz.f90...)

# convert CMake list to string for PROPERTY COMPILE_FLAGS
set(MPI_Fortran_COMPILE_FLAGS_STR "")
foreach(ELEMENT ${MPI_Fortran_COMPILE_FLAGS})
    set(MPI_Fortran_COMPILE_FLAGS_STR  "${MPI_Fortran_COMPILE_FLAGS_STR } ${ELEMENT}")
endforeach()

set_property(SOURCE ${MPI_SOURCES} PROPERTY COMPILE_FLAGS ${MPI_Fortran_COMPILE_FLAGS_STR})

...later...
add_executable(streetcanyon ${MPI_SOURCES} ${NO_MPI_SOURCES})
```

Comment: Thank you! Your explanation is very thorough, I'm going to try it out as soon as possible. Hopefully I'll be able to get back to you with positive news